# How much air does it take to lift the seeds?

Tags: pressure, water, air, density

I have a vessel with seed and water in side. The is a total of 6100 Lbs. and water is 523.6 Gals. the bulk density of the seed is 178 Lbs/CuFt.
[image: Tank Detail]

The water seed mix is expected to be 8' above the bottom of the cone. We will be adding the water at the bottom of the cone.

We need the CFM and Pressure necessary to lift the seed and agitate from a static position.